# Alterar Divs de pagina e IDs especificas com cálculos

Tags: jquery

Fala galera, tenho a seguinte situação em meu site, na página de carrinhos tem uma div que preciso alterar o conteúdo dela e colocar uns cálculos de acordo com o valor total, deixa passar os parametro:

O código vai ficar dentro do seguinte  if:

```
 {% if pages.current == 'checkout_cart' %}

 {% endif %}
```

A div completa é a seguinte:

```
<div class="board">
  <h2 class="color" id="topo">Frete</h2>
</div>
```

A div do valor total é a seguinte:

```
<div id="mostra_total" class="valores_carrinho">40,00</div>
```

O que eu preciso alterar:

Pegar o ID topo: `<h2 class="color" id="topo">Frete</h2>`, onde ta escrito frete preciso alterar para a seguinte váriável:

Se o valor total for menor que 200, mostrar a mensagem no lugar do Frete:
Faltam X reais para seu frete ficar Grátis! O cálculo seria 200 - VALOR TOTAL, pois apartir de 200 reais o frete ficaria grátis.

Se o valor total for mais que 200, mostrar a mensagem: Frete Grátis!

Editando, surgiu uma variável para subtração:

```
<div id="frete7" class="valores_carrinho">30</div>
```

Essa variável tem que ser subtraída do valor total na soma, pois ela vai ser somada independentemente dos produtos.

Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
id="mostra_total" Valores do carrinho = 40,00
id="frete7" Valores do carrinho = 30,00
```

Ele vai somar os 40 + 30, porém o cálculo para os 200 restantes devem ser apenas do mostra_total, ou seja precisa subtraior o valor do frete

```
200 -(mostra_total - frete7)
Valor total para frete grátis = 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo exemplo de como fazer:

```
$(function() {
   try {
       var valor = parseFloat($('#mostra_total').html().replace(',','.'));
       var frete7 = parseFloat($('#frete7').html().replace(',','.'));

       if((valor - frete7) > 200) {
            $('#topo').html('Frete grátis');
       } else {
            $('#topo').html('Faltam R$' + (200 - (valor  -frete7)).toFixed(2)+''.replace('.',',') + ' para você obter frete grátis!');
       }
   } catch (e) {
       $('#topo').html('Erro verifique se o valor exibido está no formato "41,00"! Detalhes técnicos: ' + e);
   }
});
```

> Exemplo no JSFiddler

https://jsfiddle.net/9e94ayvx/